# Prevent CSS footer from scrolling

Tags: css, footer

```
#bottom_fade {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background: url("bottom-fade.png");
            background-repeat:repeat-x;
            height: 400px;
            z-index: 2;
            }
        .categories {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            color:black;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            font-family: 15px 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
            margin-left: -200px;
            z-index: 1;
            }
        .categories td {
            width: 200px;
            }
```

you may see the result of the above code [here](http://saturnix.altervista.org/CV/index.html).
Try to resize your browser window so that you're forced to scroll to see the whole text in the table.

As you scroll, you may see that `#bottom_fade` will not remain sticked to the bottom of the page but will follow your scrolling. I don't want that to happen: how can I say to bottom_fade to ALWAYS stays attached to the bottom of the browser window, no matter what happens to the scrollbar?

Many thanks!

Comment: it's unrelated but you might consider setting `pointer-events:none` on your footer, it interrupts selecting text, see: [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

Comment: oh! thanks a lot dude, didn't even considered that. I'll add it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
#bottom_fade {
        position: absolute;
}
```

to

```
#bottom_fade {
        position: fixed;
};
```

and it should work like a charm.

(nice effect by the way!)

Comment: +1 and thanks for the answer. However, with your solution now the scrollbar doesn't show up (I'm using Safari). Is there any way I can still scroll the table while maintaining the effect? I saw this on many websites...

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, it seems to work on Firefox. Are you sure you put the fixed on the correct element? (On your site I noticed you put #categories's position on fixed...)

Comment: I am an idiot. I was changing the wrong selector, it works fine now. thx!